# Regex, Remove text NOT between tags

Tags: regex, excel, notepad++

I need to remove all text that is not between the tags `<p>` and `</p>`. There can be many `<p>` tags in each cell. The content before `<p>` and after `</p>` is different in each row.

Example

```
<h1>Curly Krans Daggdroppar 30cm LED</h1><h2>Beskrivning</h2><div id="more_info_sheets" class="sheets align_justify"><div id="idTab1" class="rte"><div id="more_info_sheets" class="sheets align_justify"><div id="idTab1" class="rte"><p>En krans med en snygg och intressant design. </p><p>Kransen har 30st ej utbytbara små LED lampor.</p><p>Finns i tre olika färger, välj mellan, koppar, mässing och krom.</p></div></div></div></div>
```

Should be

```
<p>En krans med en snygg och intressant design. </p><p>Kransen har 30st ej utbytbara små LED lampor.</p><p>Finns i tre olika färger, välj mellan, koppar, mässing och krom.</p>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is your environment? how do you want to remove this?

Comment: I want to remove all H1 and H2 text and also all div tags. Need to be done in Notepad++ or Excel from a .csv file. My goal is to only get a clean text with the p-tags.

Comment: I can remove everything before first <p> with ^.*?(?=<p>) but how do I remove everything after last</p>?

Comment: so the stalk regex response is not to use regex on markup. that there are better tools such as xPath for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the match expression to only capture the desired group of

tags instead of replacing the rest of the text. However here it is the other option for the regular expresion:

**Match all your p groups**

```
<p>.*<\/p>
```

**Match each p group separatedly**

```
<p>.*?<\/p>
```

**Match non p groups**

```
(^.*?(?=<p>))|((?<=<\/p>)<[^p].*)
```